# jQuery overloading based on input type

Tags: jquery, triggers, overloading, forms

I would like to create a jQuery function that I can attach to form elements change() events, but have the function decide what to do based on the type (input, select, radio, password) of form element.

Problem is, I'm not sure of the best approach - write a large function that decides internally what to do, or write a sort of factory function that attaches an appropriate function to the element based on its type... am I reinventing the wheel? i.e. is there a default way of doing something like this in jQuery.

[Additional: if it influences the decision, the function needs to be called on load(), as well as say on change(), and it would be nice to be able to apply/call? the function just the once]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want compartmentalized fairly easily with a few switches:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
   return this.each(function() {
     switch(this.nodeName) {
       case "INPUT":
         switch(this.type) {
           case "radio":
             $(this).change(function() { .... });
             break;
           case "text":
             $(this).change(function() { .... });
             break;
           /*password, etc....*/
         }
         break;
       case "SELECT":
         $(this).change(function() { .... });
         break;
       case "TEXTAREA":
         $(this).change(function() { .... });
         break;
     }         
   });
};
```

Now whether this is the best approach is certainly up for debate...it depends if you have a unique behavior for each, or some of them share behaviors, in which case you'll probably want to define common functions in a closure and reference those, for example:

```
(function($) {
    function method1() { ... }
    function method2() { ... }
    function method3() { ... }

    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
       return this.each(function() {
         switch(this.nodeName) {
           case "INPUT":
             switch(this.type) {
               case "radio":
                 $(this).change(method1);
                 break;
               case "text":
                 $(this).change(method3);
                 break;
               /*password, etc....*/
             }
             break;
           case "SELECT":
             $(this).change(method1);
             break;
           case "TEXTAREA":
             $(this).change(method2);
             break;
         }         
       });
    };    
})(jQuery);
```

You could do this at least 20 ways, this is just a suggestion if each element and type has a specific behavior, which *sounds* like the case from your question.  If it isn't just ignore me :)

Comment: This looks like it might be just right :-) Am I right in thinking I could then include something like `method1(this);$(this).change(method1);` in the switch statement, to have it run when the function is first applied to the element? via `$('#element').myPlugIn();` ?

Comment: :-( Sadly not. How do I apply the method1() function to an element immediately, as well as attach it to change() in the switch statement?

Comment: @Dycey - you can call `.change()` to trigger the event right after binding it, for example: `$(this).change(method1).change();`

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to ether trigger different jquery functions on different types of input and then call some other functions (or the same javascript function with the type of input as a parameter), or to write like you say a type of factory function that can decide what action to take based on the type of input control thas was changed.